# How to Have Blender play "Animation 2"

Tags: animation, armature

I'm trying to import an FBX to Blender and when I do, it stays in it's Idle position. I opened the animation with Windows' 3D Viewer, and on the bottom it said it was playing "Animation 1," which is the Idle animation:

[image]

When I open the drop down menu, I can play Animation 2, which is the animation I want.

So, how do I make Blender play Animation 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select which animations to play by going to the Dope sheet > Action Editor then pressing the dope sheet icon in the middle. It'll open a drop down menu of all the animations, just select one and play the animation as usual.

Comment: THANK YOU! This had been driving me crazy for hours!